# ClueTips - Text isn't readable, doesn't look like demo

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, cluetip

ClueTips is making the box look like this.  I can barely read it.  Where might I be going wrong?

[image]

Much thanks for any help.  My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-us" xml:lang="en-us" >
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/media/blueprint/screen.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/media/blueprint/print.css" type="text/css" media="print">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/media/cluetip/jquery.cluetip.css" type="text/css" media="print">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/media/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/media/cluetip/jquery.cluetip.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a.tips').cluetip();
});
</script>
</head>
<body class="search">
        <table id="search_results">

            <tr>
                <td><a class="tips" rel="/plasmid/1/" href="/plasmid/1/">SV40</a></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><a class="tips" rel="/plasmid/1/" href="/plasmid/4/">CAG</a></td>
            </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is the bluetip stylesheet getting loaded?

Comment: You mean the cluetip stylesheet? Firebug shows the stylesheet and I can view it from Firebug so I'd assume that means it's getting loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah fixed it.  I copied the `<link rel="stylesheet"...` line for the cluetip css from another line and it had media=print.  It needed to say media=screen.